# Priority of Da Coda vs. Repeat sign

Tags: notation, repeats

There are three different cases I can think of, with a *Da Coda* embedded within repeat signs. My question for these three cases is the same:

**Do you jump to the *Coda* right when you reach the *Da Coda* or do you do the repeat first and then jump to the *Coda*?**

With the examples below, this means: when do you skip bar 3, and when do you repeat bars 2 and 3?

1. In this first case, we just have a Da Coda between two repeat signs. My assumption is that you do bars 1-2-3-2-4.

[image: example with repeat, "da coda", and coda]

2. In this second case, let's add a *Da Capo* on the 2nd repeat sign (and I assume it would work the same with a *Da Segno* if the *Segno* as situated before the 1st repeat sign). My assumption is that you do bars 1-2-3-2-**3-1-2-3-2**-4.

[image: example with repeat, "da capo", "da coda", and coda]

3. Finally, we could precise *Al Coda* on our *Da Capo* (and again, I assume this to be similar to a *Da Segno*). My assumption is that you'd do 1-2-3-2-**3-1-2**-4.

[image: example with repeat, "da capo al coda", "da coda", and coda]

Comment: Are these real examples, or contrived?  If you're interested in how you would write this, you should do something that cannot be ambiguous.

Comment: @MatthewRead All these are made up to illustrate my question. They also come from a software I used to use years ago: GuitarPro. The assumptions of bar sequences are from what the software would play, and the notations are what the software would write. I am both interested in what these notations mean, and how to get these bar sequences with the proper markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, *Da Coda* is literally  "the Coda" and tells you that you are at the coda, not to go to it. If it was instead just a coda sign then in conjunction with a *D.C. al Coda* or *D.S. al Coda* as seen in your last example it would then instruct you to go to the Coda.

If you are not instructed to go to the Coda by D.C. or D.S. you don't take it. In the first two examples, you would never get to the Coda even if the sign was there instead as nothing is instructing you to take it.

As for the repeats, typically repeats are not taken after a D.C. or D.S. so you would just go to the Coda once you get to it and not worry about repeats if it was inside one.

[This site](http://www.music-mind.com/Music/mpage6.HTM) has pretty good examples for the two ways I said  codas could be used and a little later I'll post how you could use codas in your first two examples.

Comment: Linguistically speaking, what you say makes sense. But *Da Capo* and *Da Segno* do instruct you to go respectively to "the beginning" and to "the sign", do then *Da Coda* would be the only one not to follow this rule?

Comment: _Da coda_ = "From the tail", surely? The usual marker for the jump to the coda is the symbol mentioned in Dom's article (�).

Comment: @Sheraff Think of it this way. In a coda you go forward. In the other two you go backward hence why it is though of differently and still you need to be instructed to take the coda.

Comment: @Patrx2 while it could be, it does quite make sense since you are going to not coming from the tail.

Comment: @Dom, exactly. I have never seen _Da coda_ used. The usual markers are Dal segno al coda and Da capo al coda ("from the sign to the tail" and "from the head to the tail" respectively). From the symbol or start, the music is played until it reaches the cross-in-circle symbol or "al coda" or "to coda", whence it jumps to the coda.

Answer (score 1):

'To coda' is the usual form.   There's no general rule (or there hasn't been since 18th century dance suites).    Write 'DS al coda (with repeat)' or 'DS al coda (no repeat)'.  Maybe even a reminder at the 'to coda' point: 'make repeat on DS' or 'no repeat on DS'.